# Why boiling point of water is much higher that expected from the diagram?

Tags: physical-chemistry, water

Explain why the boiling point of water is much higher than expected based on the size of the molecule. Has it got to do something with the intermolecular forces ? Please explain.

Comment: Hi lizzy,  welcome to Chem.SE! We require you to show your efforts on this question. Why do you think so.?Please add this to your question. Thanks! “Homework questions must demonstrate some effort to understand the underlying concepts.” This is our policy.

Comment: If you still don’t have an idea, I can give you a clue.

Answer (score 1):

A water molecule has a small size, and its high boiling point is indeed anomalous with the general trend of boiling points of molecules of similar size as water molecule.

Now the high boiling point of water molecules can be explained on the basis of $\ce{H}$ bonding that takes place among the water molecules in liquid state. A water molecule can form a maximum of $4$ $\ce{H}$ bonds. This increases the effective size of water molecules too, which in turn increases the *van der Waals* forces operating in water molecules.

The two reasons for high boiling point of water are -

1. Formation of $\ce{H}$ bonds, which requires more energy for breaking the 'extra' bonds.
2. Increase in *van der Waals* forces, as a result of which we need to supply more temperature for water to boil, or change from liquid state to vapour state.

Answer (score 0):

Because it can form hydrogen bonds between its molecules.

The greater the forces of attraction, the higher the boiling point, or the greater the polarity, the higher the boiling point. Water molecules in liquid state have the ability to form hydrogen bonds with each other. These hydrogen bonds are some of the strongest of all intermolecular forces, so a large amount of energy is needed to break these interactions −  this is the main reason why water has such a high relative boiling point.